# Jquery setTimeout in Object

Tags: jquery, settimeout

My JS:

```
timeout_on = {}
timeout_off = {}


$('.flex_section a').each(function(){
   var a = $(this).attr('id');

   $('.flex_section #' + a).hover(function(){ 

       timeout_on['some_id' + a] = setTimeout(function() { popup_show(a); }, 300);

   });
})

function popup_show(type){
    console.log(timeout_on)
}
```

Why in console log i have someting like:

```
Object {some_id: 1} 
Object {some_id: 5} 
Object {some_id: 9}
```

soo the number is +4 for every .hover

What this integer means and why it isn't 1,2,3,4 ... ? I thought that this will be a number for setTimeout like 50, 231 etc. and then i will clearTimeout to have 0, but it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the spec says is that you will get an integer back, it doesn't say anything about an order.

Odds are, dollar to donuts, that some of the timers numbers have been used by other processes or threads.

Comment: ok thanks, soo every thing is ok in here .. i must search for bug in other place :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Should be a comment but I need to post code)*

You code is unnecessarily complicated. No need for the `.each()`  loop:

```
$('.flex_section a').hover(function(){ 
   var a = this.id;
   timeout_on['some_id' + a] = setTimeout(function() { popup_show(a); }, 300);
});
```

BTW, if you use the ID like this (especially by passing it to the `popup_show` function), you are most likely doing something wrong in the big picture